# Phantom compile errors after upgrading NuGet package

Tags: c#, webforms, rdlc

I had a Microsoft WebForms report viewer library version 10 referenced in my project, and I decided to remove that reference and add the version 150 NuGet package. However now I get a bunch of compile errors like so:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'LocalReport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

and other similar errors. The weird thing is, when I open up the files containing the errors, the errors go away, but as soon as I try to build my project, they reappear! What's going on here? How can I compile my project without errors?

Comment: Oh wait a second, I enabled display of compiler warnings and found this:

The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1".

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the report viewer library I added the reference to required .NET Framework version 4.6, but my projects were only using version 4.51. Upgrading to v4.7 solved the problem.

Comment: Mark your answer as the solution please.

Comment: I can't yet, I have to wait 2 days.